# LeetCode: Find And Replace in String C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, strings

It took me a while to solve this question and there are corner cases i missed hence the 4 unit tests.
please review for performance. and if you can treat this as a review for a 45 mins programming interview.

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-and-replace-in-string/

> To some string S, we will perform some replacement operations that
> replace groups of letters with new ones (not necessarily the same
> size).
>
> Each replacement operation has 3 parameters: a starting index i, a
> source word x and a target word y.  The rule is that if x starts at
> position i in the original string S, then we will replace that
> occurrence of x with y.  If not, we do nothing.
>
> For example, if we have S = "abcd" and we have some replacement
> operation i = 2, x = "cd", y = "ffff", then because "cd" starts at
> position 2 in the original string S, we will replace it with "ffff".
>
> Using another example on S = "abcd", if we have both the replacement
> operation i = 0, x = "ab", y = "eee", as well as another replacement
> operation i = 2, x = "ec", y = "ffff", this second operation does
> nothing because in the original string S[2] = 'c', which doesn't match
> x[0] = 'e'.
>
> All these operations occur simultaneously.  It's guaranteed that there
> won't be any overlap in replacement: for example, S = "abc", indexes =
> [0, 1], sources = ["ab","bc"] is not a valid test case.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: S = "abcd", indexes = [0,2], sources = ["a","cd"], targets =
> ["eee","ffff"] Output: "eeebffff" Explanation: "a" starts at index 0
> in S, so it's replaced by "eee". "cd" starts at index 2 in S, so it's
> replaced by "ffff". Example 2:
>
> Input: S = "abcd", indexes = [0,2], sources = ["ab","ec"], targets =
> ["eee","ffff"] Output: "eeecd" Explanation: "ab" starts at index 0 in
> S, so it's replaced by "eee".  "ec" doesn't starts at index 2 in the
> original S, so we do nothing. Notes:
>
> 0 <= indexes.length = sources.length = targets.length <= 100 0 <
> indexes[i] < S.length <= 1000 All characters in given inputs are
> lowercase letters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace StringQuestions
{      
    [TestClass]
    public class FindReplaceStringTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string S = "abcd";
            int[] indexes = { 0, 2 };
            string[] sources = { "a", "cd" };
            string[] targets = { "eee", "ffff" };
            string output = "eeebffff";
            Assert.AreEqual(output, FindReplaceStringClass.FindReplaceString(S, indexes, sources, targets));
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFailMethod1()
        {
            string S = "abcd";
            int[] indexes = { 0, 2 };
            string[] sources = { "ab", "ec" };
            string[] targets = { "eee", "ffff" };
            string output = "eeecd";
            Assert.AreEqual(output, FindReplaceStringClass.FindReplaceString(S, indexes, sources, targets));

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFailMethod2()
        {
            string S = "vmokgggqzp";
            int[] indexes = { 3, 5, 1 };
            string[] sources = { "kg", "ggq", "mo" };
            string[] targets = { "s", "so", "bfr" };
            string output = "vbfrssozp";
            Assert.AreEqual(output, FindReplaceStringClass.FindReplaceString(S, indexes, sources, targets));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFailMethod3()
        {
            string S = "jjievdtjfb";
            int[] indexes = { 4,6,1 };
            string[] sources = { "md", "tjgb", "jf" };
            string[] targets = { "foe", "oov", "e" };
            string output = "jjievdtjfb";
            Assert.AreEqual(output, FindReplaceStringClass.FindReplaceString(S, indexes, sources, targets));
        }
        
    }
}

public class FindReplaceStringClass
{
    public static string FindReplaceString(string S, int[] indexes, string[] sources, string[] targets)
    {
        var index2strings = new SortedDictionary<int, Tuple<string, string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
        {
            index2strings.Add(indexes[i], new Tuple<string, string>(sources[i], targets[i]));
        }

        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        int curr = 0;//current s pointer
        foreach (var item in index2strings)
        {
            var index = item.Key;
            var source = item.Value.Item1;
            var target = item.Value.Item2;
            //check each index if source appears in s
            for (int k = curr; k < index; k++)
            {
                res.Append(S[k]);
                curr++;
            }
            //check the entire prefix is found
            bool isFound = true;
            for (int sIndx = index, j = 0; sIndx < index + source.Length; sIndx++, j++)
            {
                if (S[sIndx] != source[j])
                {
                    isFound = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isFound)
            {
                continue;
            }
            curr = index + source.Length;
            //append new string
            foreach (var t in target)
            {
                res.Append(t);
            }
        }
        //the rest of s
        for (int i = curr; i < S.Length; i++)
        {
            res.Append(S[i]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the old `Tuple` objects, you should use `ValueTuple`. They are more flexible and easier to read and maintain according to names and is further more elaborated and incorporated in C# as language. So your Dictionary could look like:

```
  var index2strings = new SortedDictionary<int, (string source, string target)>();
  for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
  {
    index2strings.Add(indexes[i], (sources[i], targets[i]));
  }
```

---

You can benefit from setting the capacity of the string builder to a large value, - maybe as:

```
  StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(S.Length * 2);
```

---

Because `KeyValuePair<K,V>` provides a ["decontructor"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct), you can replace this:

> ```
>   foreach (var item in index2strings)
>   {
>     var index = item.Key;
>     var source = item.Value.Item1;
>     var target = item.Value.Item2;
> ```

with this:

```
  foreach ((var index, (var source, var target)) in index2strings)
  {
```

if you use `ValueTuple` as suggested above.

---

This:

> ```
>     for (int k = curr; k < index; k++)
>     {
>       res.Append(S[k]);
>       curr++;
>     }
> ```

can be replaced with:

```
    int length = index - curr;
    res.Append(S.Substring(curr, length));
    curr += length;
```

According to my measurements it's cheaper to add one string as a whole than a sequence of its chars.

---

Likewise can this:

> ```
>     //check the entire prefix is found
>     bool isFound = true;
>     for (int sIndx = index, j = 0; sIndx < index + source.Length; sIndx++, j++)
>     {
>       if (S[sIndx] != source[j])
>       {
>         isFound = false;
>         break;
>       }
>     }
>     if (!isFound)
>     {
>       continue;
>     }
> ```

be replaced with:

```
    if (S.Substring(index, source.Length) != source)
    {
      continue;
    }
```

and this:

> ```
>     foreach (var t in target)
>     {
>       res.Append(t);
>     }
> ```

with:

```
    res.Append(target);
```

and finally this:

> ```
>   for (int i = curr; i < S.Length; i++)
>   {
>     res.Append(S[i]);
>   }
> ```

with:

```
  res.Append(S.Substring(curr));
```

When doing so it seems that you can cut the duration to about a little lesser than half the time.

Comment: You can cut all the substring allocations with [`Append(String, Int32, Int32)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_StringBuilder_Append_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_) and `S.IndexOf(source, curr, source.Length, StringComparison.Ordinal)`